# regex issue in emacs lisp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have a problem about regex in Emacs.
For example, there is a string:
`abcdef def`

I want to write a regex that only matches ‘def’ which follows ‘abc’. That is to say, I just want to capture ‘abcdef’, not ‘def.
And I hope the point can be located between ‘abc’ and ‘def’, like ‘abc^def’. ( ^ stands for point)
I remember there is a way to do it in Perl, but I am not sure if it is feasible in ELISP.

Comment: Note that Emacs regexps have no zero-width look-ahead/behind assertions, which is most likely the Perl regexp feature you were thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun foo ()
  (when (re-search-forward "abc\\(def\\)" nil nil)
    (goto-char (match-beginning 1))))
```

But really you should read about regexp matching in Emacs Lisp -- in the Elisp manual, starting at node `Regular Expressions`.  There is little excuse for posting such a basic question without looking for the answer first, yourself.

StackOverflow is for posing and answering programming questions, and you are expected to clearly specfy the problem, *show the code you have already used* to try to solve it, say what your code does that you do not expect, etc.

People are happy to help, in general, but a minimum of effort is expected from those asking for help.

Comment: thank you very much @Drew, this is what i want. i am a elisp newbie, :) thank you for you advice

Comment: No problem with being a newbie. We are *all* Elisp newbies, in some areas, at least.  Please do read a bit of that manual section, even if you find it heavy-going.  It is very helpful, and "getting" regexps in Emacs will greatly improve your use of it (and your fun using it).